# Laravel или PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, yii2

Недавно я учил PHP. Помогите при выборе Laravel или Yii2 что лучше?
Всем спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А что современнее? На какой фреймворк спрос? Ваши предпочтения?

Comment: Однозначный ответ вам тут никто дать не сможет. Это исключительно субъективные вещи. Лучше для кого? Для меня? Для Вас? Для Пети? ...и лучше в каких условиях и на каких проектах? Потому что в разных ситуациях, на разных проектах они могут вести себя по разному. В одном случае будет лучше одно, в другом-другое. Одна команда сможет вытянуть на одном фреймворке практически все что угодно и провалить все с другим, только из-за предпочтений, взглядов, привычек и принципов проектирования. С другой командой будет все ровно - да наоборот.

Comment: Поэтому тут Вам никто не советчик. Выбор за Вами только. Придется потратить немножко времени. Изучить хотя бы поверхностно принципы которые лежат в основе каждого из них. Посмотреть примерно как и что на каждом из них разрабатывается. Вам же с этим работать потом! Как Вы будете работать с тем что Вам не нравится...даже если вам все говорят что это лучше. Но толку от этого, если Вы сами не понимаете а с чего он лучше. И будете как тот ёжик, который кололся но продолжал.

Comment: Так что смотрите сами...я к примеру из этих двоих предпочитаю Symfony) мне он ближе и для меня он однозначно лучше двух оставшихся...и мало ли что еще Вы пропустили. Так что смотрите и выбирайте сами.

Answer (score 1):

Главное не фреймворк, а руки из плеч. Учи и Yii2, Laravel и Symfony. Начать можно с любого. Сначала один, потом другой, потом третий. Я пишу на всех трёх например.